# not able to get the count the response getting through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, count

I have a form that is used to upload multiple files on click of submit button.

For example i am uploading the following files

> student.png
>
> animal.png
>
> pet.png

I am using the following ajax to send the values at the backend ([code reference taken from](https://www.sourcecodester.com/tutorials/php/10443/multiple-file-uploads-progress-bar-using-javascript-php.html)).

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:this.vpb_settings.vpb_server_url,
    data:dataString,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success:function(response)
    {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

When i try to print the response through "console.log()", i get the list of the names of the files that were uploaded, which is one of my requirement.
So after using "console.log(response)" i get the output as

> student
>
> animal
>
> pet

Now i wish to to calculate the number of names that i get, for this i used this code, "console.log(response.length)" but i got the output as

```
7
6
3
```

> Whereas i want the response as 3 because there are 3 items in the list

can anyone please tell how this can be done

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using one ajax call per file, so of course, each `response` is the name of one file (a string), not an array, hence

1. `'student'.length` => 7
2. `'animal'.length` => 6
3. `'pet'.length` => 3

If you need the amount of files you could use a global counter, like this:

```
var counter = 0; //<--needs to be declared somewhere it gets initialized once only
function someFuncContainingTheAjaxCall(){
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:this.vpb_settings.vpb_server_url,
    data:dataString,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success:function(response)
    {
        console.log('Files so far ' + (++counter));
    }
});
}
```

HIH

Comment: I tried your code, but the response that i am getting now is 1 1 1, whereas i want count of total number of files

Comment: @lakshmipriya, sorry, forgot to mention you need to declare `var counter = 0;` outside whatever function the ajax call is in, so `counter` is not re-declared on every new run, I'll try to illustrate it in the edit

Comment: @ Scaramouche thanks for the response but still getting the same result

Comment: can u post some more of your code so I can get a picture of the structure and where you would declare `counter` if you were to implement my answer?

Comment: the code is very long and i have given the link in post pls check the link

Answer (score 0):

You can create any  variable in outer scope and increase it on success callback. Also you will need to reset it to  0 before do call.

Comment: `var counter = 0;`
`$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:this.vpb_settings.vpb_server_url,
    data:dataString,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success:function(response)
    {
        counter++;
        console.log(counter);
    }
});`
It should work.

Comment: @lakshmipriya could you please provide  more your code, where you call $.ajax and  declare  counter variable?

Comment: the code is very long thats why i have given the link in post.you can there.

Comment: I check it and  find  already implementer counter `file_counter`. Did you try to use it?

Comment: the link i have given in the post i am  using the javascript code so there once the file is uploaded and  again am choosing some other file all the files are uploading again i need to solve that issue